# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For some reason I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Project_6\Quiz\database.class.php on line 55

This is probably because the $db variable is not an object of PDO, although it is. Does it have anything to do with the fact that its in the `__construct` method? Or do I need to pass it in the insertquery function?

Also I call an object of my class database in my index.php, where also my HTML is located.
In index.php I also call the Insertquery function

This is my DB class:

```
class Database{

    //constantes zijn geen properties want die kan je niet veranderen
    const DB_HOSTNAME = "localhost";
    const DB_USERNAME = "root";
    const DB_PASSWORD = "";
    const DB_NAME = "quiz";
    private $typedb = "mysql";
    public $db;
    //protected $_sql;

    public function __construct(){

        //heeft geen conditie nodig. moet uitgevoerd worden dus try
        try
        {
            //object aanroepen van de class PDO (ingebouwd in PHP)
            $db = new PDO($this->typedb.':host='.self::DB_HOSTNAME.';dbname='.self::DB_NAME, self::DB_USERNAME, self::DB_PASSWORD);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        //anders wat? heeft wel een conditie nodig, bij een exception van PDO dus, die store je in de $e
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

    }



    //$values verwacht $_POST waardes dus is al array
    public function insertQuery($table, array $cols, array $values){


        //$insert in een for each loop
        $column_list = implode(",", $cols); //returns string: 'username, password'

        $post_params = implode(",", $values);
        $count = 0;

        //de PDO parameters maken, met een ':'voor de columnnaam
        foreach($cols as $insert_values){
            $count++;

            //doe dit voor het aantal kolommen
            if($count < $cols){

                $insert_values = ":".$column_list;

            }
        }
        $query = 'INSERT INTO $table ($column_list) VALUES ($insert_values)'; //"INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)
        $insert = $this->db->prepare($query);
        //voor elke kolom een binding
        foreach($values as $post_params){
            $count++;
            if($count < $cols){

                $insert->bindParam($insert_values, $post_params);
            }
        }
        $insert->execute();


    }

    public function selectQuery(){

        // SELECT FROM WHERE ORDER BY

    }

    public function updateQuery(){


    }

    public function deleteQuery(){


    }



}
```

This is my INDEX.PHP code:

```
    //require_once omdat als file niet werkt of gevonden kan worden het script niet werkt
    require_once 'database.class.php';
    require_once 'user.class.php';

    $db = new Database();

    if(isset($_POST['reg_submit'])){

        $users_cols = array("username", "password");
        $post_values = array($_POST['regUsername'], $_POST['regPassword']);

        $db->insertQuery('users', $users_cols, $post_values);
    }
```

Comment: plz read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and you should format your code and highlight line 55

Comment: `$query = 'INSERT INTO $table ($column_list) VALUES ($insert_values)'` variables are not interpolated inside single quotes strings. and most likely `$insert_values = ":".$column_list;` is just getting overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You don't save your db handle in your public variable. You use here `$this-db`.

```
$insert = $this->db->prepare($query);
```

But in your constructor you don't save the PDO connection in that variable.

```
$db = new PDO($this->typedb.':host='.self::DB_HOSTNAME.';dbname='.self::DB_NAME, self::DB_USERNAME, self::DB_PASSWORD);
```

that should be:

```
$this->db = new PDO($this->typedb.':host='.self::DB_HOSTNAME.';dbname='.self::DB_NAME, self::DB_USERNAME, self::DB_PASSWORD);
```

Otherwise the connection is not saved in `$this->db`.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, you instanciate the PDO class into the `$db` variable. But then you try using it with `$this->db`.

When you assign the new object to the variable $db, you create a local variable inside the constructor. It will vanish after the constructor is done.

If you want to save the option into the property `db` of the class, you have to use `$this->db` instead!

Answer (score 0):

In PHP classes, variables must be set using `$this->` to make them accessible to other methods in the class.

In the constructor, you are initializing the database connection like this:

```
$db = new PDO($this->typedb.':host='.self::DB_HOSTNAME.';dbname='.self::DB_NAME, self::DB_USERNAME, self::DB_PASSWORD);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

However, the $db variable only exists until the method finishes running. To make it live for the life of the class, assign it to the class itself via `$this->`:

```
$this->db = new PDO($this->typedb.':host='.self::DB_HOSTNAME.';dbname='.self::DB_NAME, self::DB_USERNAME, self::DB_PASSWORD);
$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Now the PDO object is a member of the class, and can be accessed elsewhere by referencing the same name:

```
$insert = $this->db->prepare($query);
```